# identify the sender FORM in the $_POST array

Tags: html, forms

I have few forms on the same page, just like this:

```
<form action='' method='POST' id='PERSON'>
  <input type='hidden' id='ID' name='ID' value='123'>
  <input type='text' id='NAME' name='NAME' value='John Smith'>
  <button type='submit'>submit</button>
</form>

<form action='' method='POST' id='PRODUCT'>
  <input type='hidden' id='ID' name='ID' value='123'>
  <input type='text' id='NAME' name='NAME' value='sample whatever'>
  <button type='submit'>submit</button>
</form>
```

Is there any way to identify the sender form in the $_POST/$_REQUEST array without any modification on the forms? The problem is when I'm processing these requests I have no idea where the ID and the NAME params came from. The only way I can think of is to modify each input's name like this: name='PERSON.ID' and name='PRODUCT.ID', but someone might have a better idea than that.

Comment: You can create a input type hidden and put the name of the form. Some problem with this?

Comment: Well, it will require some modification in the forms, apart from that I like your idea, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle that by getting ;

1. A hidden input field
2. The name or value of the submit button

in handle request. Here is example;

```
<form action='' method='POST' id='PERSON'>
  <input type='hidden' id='ID' name='ID' value='123'>
  <input type='text' id='NAME' name='NAME' value='John Smith'>
  <input type='hidden' name='formType' value='form1'>
  <button type='submit'>submit</button>
</form>

<form action='' method='POST' id='PRODUCT'>
  <input type='hidden' id='ID' name='ID' value='123'>
  <input type='text' id='NAME' name='NAME' value='sample whatever'>
  <input type='hidden' name='formType' value='form2'>
  <button type='submit'>submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: OK this is won't requires too much coding, so it will do the job, thanks! I will give same name to the hidden inputs, so that will be more easier to process.